# ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero i cant see any error

Tags: python, function

Please help to solve this. I will be very thankful!

```
t = int(input())
count = 0 
m = []
for i in range(0,t):
    num = int(input())
    m.append(num)
for z in m:
    for i in range(0,z):
        if z%i==0:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 0
        if count % 2 == 1:
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
        
    count = None
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "solution.py", line 9, in 
> if z%i==0:
> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: The stacktrace tells you all you need to know: at line 9 you did `z%i` which caused `ZeroDivisionError` because `i` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 as starting value to avoid this error(Zero division)

```
for i in range(1,z):
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is defined in range(0,z), it always starts from zero.
Mathematically the module of zero is undefined, that's why you're getting the error.